# Is there a way to filter $OpenFileDialog.filter by more than extension?

Tags: powershell, openfiledialog

I'd like to search for all files that end in .att, but exclude anything that starts with `sorted_`.

```
Function Get-AttName($initialDirectory)
{   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.windows.forms”) |
 Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = “All files (*.att)| *.att”
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-FileName
```

And here are some files:

```
test.att
sorted_test.att
Nav_HF_New.att
Sorted_Nav_HF_New.att
```

I want to only be able to select `test.att` and `Nav_HF_New.att`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, an exclusion filter is not possible. Best you could do is handle the `FileOk` event and deny closing the dialog when the choosen file name starts with "sorted_".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately [Wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2) don't have an option to *"not match" something* as far as I know, however there is one workaround we could use via string manipulation.

By looking at [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) from the [`FileDialog.Filter` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) Docs we can tell that we can add several patterns to the filter expression separating them with a semi-colon `;`. Following this thought, we can use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) the get all the file names in the target location and join them with a `;` and use that as our filter, which seems to work properly however it would only work in the target directory, if you want to navigate to other directory it wouldn't work unless there is a file name that matches with one of those in the target directory.

Here is the code:

```
function Get-AttName {
    param(
        [string] $InitialDirectory,
        [string] $Extension,
        [string] $Exclude
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

    $InitialDirectory = Convert-Path $initialDirectory
    $filter = (Get-ChildItem $initialDirectory -Filter $Extension |
        Where-Object Name -NotMatch $Exclude).Name -join ';'

    if(-not $filter) {
        $filter = $Extension
    }

    $OpenFileDialog = [System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog]@{
        InitialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
        Filter           = "All files ($Extension)|$filter"
    }

    if($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok') {
        $OpenFileDialog.FileName
    }
}

Get-AttName . -Extension *.att -Exclude '^sorted'
```