how do I check the user has selected a file in a powershell file selection dialog
I have been working on a script that allows a user to select a csv file from their PC to be operated on, the code I have to get the CSV file is as follows
    #function to open a file selection dialouge at the $InitialDirectory, with filetype filter $FileTypeFilter and return the file name
    function Get-File($InitialDirectory, $FileTypeFilter) {  
        $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        if ($initialDirectory) {
            $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
        }
        $OpenFileDialog.filter = $FileTypeFilter

        #setup modalform to allow the form object to always be on top
        $modalform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $modalform.TopMost = $true
    
        #open the dialouge box and ensure a file is selected
        if($NULL -ne $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($modalform).FileName){
            return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
        } 
        else {
            #if no file error and exit the script
            Throw "No File Selected!"
        }
    }

the issue I am seeing however is when the user selects a file, it fails the if statement and then throws the error. during debugging however I can see that the filename property of the $openfiledialog object is set to the appropriate filepath string
Image of variable tracking in Powershell Debugging
I have tried first opening the Dialog and then setting a variable = to the FileName as per below, however this leaves the variable blank with no contents and that too fails the check
    #function to open a file selection dialouge at the $InitialDirectory, with filetype filter $FileTypeFilter and return the file name
    function Get-File($InitialDirectory, $FileTypeFilter) {  
        $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        if ($initialDirectory) {
            $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
        }
        $OpenFileDialog.filter = $FileTypeFilter

        #setup modalform to allow the form object to always be on top
        $modalform = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $modalform.TopMost = $true
    
    
        $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($modalform)
        $file = $OpenFileDialog.FileName
        #open the dialouge box and ensure a file is selected
        if($NULL -ne $File){
            return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
        } 
        else {
            #if no file error and exit the script
            Throw "No File Selected!"
        }
    }

any help much appreciated

ShowDialog returns DialogResult so what you want is "if ShowDialog returns OK" then you can be certain that the user actually picked a file and then you can return $OpenFileDialog.FileName ;)

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73494290/15339544 your if condition should look like that

Leave the function to just handle the opening of the dialog, and take care of validation in the script. Something like:
Function Get-FilePath{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Comma Seperated Values (*.csv)|*.csv|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt",
    [String]$InitialDirectory = "C:",
    [String]$Title)

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
    $OpenFileDialog.Title = $Title
    [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$File = Get-FilePath -filter 'Comma Seperated Values (*.csv)|*.csv' -InitialDirectory "$home\documents"
Do{
    Write-Warning "You must select a CSV file"
}Until(($File = Get-FilePath -filter 'Comma Seperated Values (*.csv)|*.csv' -InitialDirectory "$home\documents"))


As Santiago notes, the .ShowDialog() returns a System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult enumeration value indicating which button was pressed to close the dialog, such as [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK.
Therefore, the conceptually most straightforward way is to test the .ShowDialog() call's return value for the enumeration value of interest (rather than comparing it to $null, which will always be $false):
        $dialogResult = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($modalform)
        if($dialogResult -eq 'OK'){
            return $OpenFileDialog.FileName
        } 
        else {
            #if no file error and exit the script
            Throw "No File Selected!"
        }   

Note that the above takes advantage of the fact that PowerShell automatically translates between enumeration values and their string representations, so that 'OK' is sufficient to refer to [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK with a System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult LHS (in other words: [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK -eq 'OK' is $true).

As for your second attempt:

If the .ShowDialog() call is canceled, the .FileName property contains '', i.e. the empty string rather than $null, so your test would have to be:
if ('' -ne $file) { ... }
which you could even simplify to if ($file) { ... }, relying on PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean coercion rules.

Also, not capturing the return value from .ShowDialog() would have output that value as part of your function's "return value", i.e. overall output. To prevent that you could have used
$null = $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($modalform)



this worked great thanks, I think I may have when I tried this originally tried
`if ($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($modalform) -eq 'OK'){}
which isn't working but pulling the result into its own object seems to have worked. Although, I am still a little confused as to why checking the filename isn't empty doesn't work?

Glad to hear it worked, @KairiRovco. However, note that $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog($modalform) -eq 'OK' should work too - no strict need for an intermediate variable. As for checking the .FileName property value: turns out that it is '' (the empty string) rather than $null if the dialog is canceled - please see my update (new bottom section), which also points out another potential problem.
